# Tensorflow gradients

Tags: tensorflow, gradient

I am trying to adapt the tf DeepDream tutorial code to work with another model. Right now when I call tf.gradients():

```
t_grad = tf.gradients(t_score, t_input)[0]
g      = sess.run(t_grad, {t_input:img0})
```

I am getting a type error:

```
TypeError: Fetch argument None of None has invalid type <type 'NoneType'>,     
must be a string or Tensor. (Can not convert a NoneType into a Tensor or 
Operation.)
```

Where should I even start to look for fixing this error?

Is it possible to use tf.gradients() with a model that has an Optimizer in it?

Comment: Is it that sess.run is expecting a list as the first argument and you gave it a tensor?

Comment: That's a good thought. I also tried it with [t_grad] as the argument. And I had the same result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm guessing your `t_grad` has some `None`s. `None` is mathematically equivalent to 0 gradient, but is returned for the special case when the cost doesn't depend on the argument it is differentiated against. There are various reasons why we don't just return 0 instead of `None` which you can see in discussion [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/783)

Because `None` can be annoying in cases like above, or when computing second derivatives, I use helper function below

```
def replace_none_with_zero(l):
  return [0 if i==None else i for i in l]
```

Comment: Thanks, that was helpful for debugging. It seems `tf.gradients()` was only returning a single `None`. In the deep dream tutorial, `t_score = tf.reduce_mean(<a tensor>)`, a scalar value. I have not changed `t_input` from the original code. I call `t_score = tf.reduce_mean(<my tensor>)` ,  `tf.gradients(t_score, t_input)` and I still get the same error because  `tf.gradients()` returns a single `None` or a single 0 if I use your helper function. It seems to me all I have done is substituted one scalar for another and yet, it works in the tutorial and not for me.

Comment: this means that the scalar you substituted does not depend on the variables being differentiated against (`tf.trainable_variables()`), hence the gradient is 0

Answer (score 2):

The following is a helpful tip for debugging `tf.gradients()`

for an invalid pair of tensors:

```
grads = tf.gradients(<a tensor>, <another tensor that doesn't depend on the first>)
```

even before you try to run `tf.gradients` in a session you can see it is invalid using `print`

```
print grads
```

It will return `[None]` a list with a single `None` in it.

If you try to run it in a session anyways:

```
results = sess.run(grads)
```

You will not get `None` again, instead you get the error message described in the question.

For a valid pair of tensors:

```
grads = tf.gradients(<a tensor>, <a related tensor>)
print grads
```

You will get something like:

```
Tensor("gradients_1/sub_grad/Reshape:0", dtype=float32)
```

In a valid situation:

```
results = sess.run(grads, {<appropriate feeds>})
print results
```

you get something like

`[array([[  4.97156498e-06,   7.87349381e-06,   9.25197037e-06, ...,
          8.72526925e-06,   6.78442757e-06,   3.85240173e-06],
       [  7.72772819e-06,   9.26370740e-06,   1.19129227e-05, ...,
          1.27088233e-05,   8.76379818e-06,   6.00637532e-06],
       [  9.46506498e-06,   1.10620931e-05,   1.43903117e-05, ...,
          1.40718612e-05,   1.08670165e-05,   7.12365863e-06],
       ..., 
       [  1.03536004e-05,   1.03090524e-05,   1.32107480e-05, ...,
          1.40605653e-05,   1.25974075e-05,   8.90011415e-06],
       [  9.69486427e-06,   8.18045282e-06,   1.12702282e-05, ...,
          1.32554378e-05,   1.13317501e-05,   7.74569162e-06],
       [  5.61043908e-06,   4.93397192e-06,   6.33513537e-06, ...,
          6.26539259e-06,   4.52598442e-06,   4.10689108e-06]], dtype=float32)]`

Comment: As it turns out, I was providing an in appropriate feed so there were in fact no gradients, which is why I was getting None. To fix the problem I just provided the appropriate feeds and it worked. I have had other similar situations that arise from using tensorflow variable scopes. To solve those other problems I carefully used tf.variable_scope.reuse_variables(). Hope that helps.

Comment: That's similar case, in which an inappropriate feed resulted in None! Thanks.

Comment: What is an "inappropriate feed" ?

Comment: There was no chain of gradients between the tensor I was asking for and the values I passed to the feed_dict.